# Has anyone gotten Brownie developer revert comments to work with Vyper?

Tags: brownie, vyper

When I try to use Brownie developer revert comments with a Vyper contract as described in the Brownie documentation here:

[Developer Revert Comments](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests-pytest-intro.html#developer-revert-comments)

Brownie does not seem to recognize the comments.

#### Environment information

- `brownie` Version: 1.18.1
- `ganache-cli` Version: 0.1.4
- `solc` Version: NA
- 'vyper' Version: 0.3.1
- Python Version: 3.9.12
- OS: linux Ubuntu 20.04.4

**Simple example to demonstrate problem:**

**contract_with_assertion.vy**

```py
# @version ^0.3.0
@payable
@external


def __init__():
    assert False # dev: developer comment
```

**test_dev_comments.py**

```py
import brownie


def test_developer_revert_comments(contract_with_assertion, accounts):
    with brownie.reverts("dev: developer comment"):
        contract_with_assertion.deploy({'from': accounts[0]})
```

**Command:** $brownie test

**Output:**

```
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/alecms/test_venv/developer_comments_example
plugins: eth-brownie-1.18.1, hypothesis-6.27.3, xdist-1.34.0, web3-5.27.0, forked-1.4.0
collected 1 item                                                               

Launching 'ganache-cli --chain.vmErrorsOnRPCResponse true --server.port 8545 --miner.blockGasLimit 12000000 --wallet.totalAccounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --wallet.mnemonic brownie'...

tests/test_dev_comments.py F                                             [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________ test_developer_revert_comments ________________________

contract_with_assertion = <brownie.network.contract.ContractContainer object at 0x7f52442aa1c0>
accounts = <brownie.network.account.Accounts object at 0x7f524a2b8100>

    def test_developer_revert_comments(contract_with_assertion, accounts):
        with brownie.reverts("dev: developer comment"):
>           contract_with_assertion.deploy({'from': accounts[0]})
E           AssertionError: Unexpected revert string ''

tests/test_dev_comments.py:10: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
Transaction sent: 0x7434cef807b909faf46a6d07b8804b19275e61847878c98a8acd85238ce9b444
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests/test_dev_comments.py::test_developer_revert_comments - Assertion...
============================== 1 failed in 1.21s ===============================
Terminating local RPC client...
```

Comment: Sad to say, but _Brownie_ may be dead.  https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1515